# How to split object type data in to multiple columns using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
array([{'name': 'pt.96qt6m0l6udrwon11jybxhvz0y7p1ixjisvowh52mtr53how1dihuaub.9q248rrj4hfm4wtbu4pavc7shb31kx7vdj75uzyy5v1hpychf3zdvamb.thdmrtukbty2v5apzwmyrghi7n7gd.s31.63z.de.', 'ttl': 60, 'type': 10, 'clas': 1, 'data': 'E9000328A013AAC5747648480103C414DCCB01070E1105A87E87061E0AE72A284E67E5D966C4751EC41ACD9AF05F911ACC0A17558DF9E1285793280A69077DFDC1860075C2811DA155CDA5E40EF89FDDE1EF67035A6E17C7C3406D89E6E9D1B857532A676193F1EE39EC2A2F334D9FDB55D097F6C038546F1E5D8C31A13A30518C94ED84AEA56E41D1F44837E0D220573184CC03E3765250129C2BE7258F4046CFDA00A74D71D9F2D0EFBE81AC2966DC07B97B3DE402B057E42DC2DE69A5463B81274E8ED0EEB18ABA6EE22713B4B55232E0A37975C4E9946F7B53216662BD6F445DE2914F09BBEA7ED6EC75C3E0142C440B719D7C5589D743A10044941CB215D7995921523DE21D63F7377E97E3A8AB23D79F55603CC2737D8015'}],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your array in `Dataframe` constructor:

```
In [199]: import numpy as np
In [198]: import pandas as pd

In [200]: s = np.array([{'name': 'pt.96qt6m0l6udrwon11jybxhvz0y7p1ixjisvowh52mtr53how1dihuaub.9q248rrj4hfm4wtbu4pavc7shb31kx7vdj75uzyy5v1hpychf3zdvamb.thdmrtukbty2v5apzwmyrghi7n7gd.s31.63z.de.', 'ttl': 60, 'type': 10, 'clas': 1, 'data': 'E9000328A013AAC5
     ...: 747648480103C414DCCB01070E1105A87E87061E0AE72A284E67E5D966C4751EC41ACD9AF05F911ACC0A17558DF9E1285793280A69077DFDC1860075C2811DA155CDA5E40EF89FDDE1EF67035A6E17C7C3406D89E6E9D1B857532A676193F1EE39EC2A2F334D9FDB55D097F6C038546F1E5D8C31A13A30518C94
     ...: ED84AEA56E41D1F44837E0D220573184CC03E3765250129C2BE7258F4046CFDA00A74D71D9F2D0EFBE81AC2966DC07B97B3DE402B057E42DC2DE69A5463B81274E8ED0EEB18ABA6EE22713B4B55232E0A37975C4E9946F7B53216662BD6F445DE2914F09BBEA7ED6EC75C3E0142C440B719D7C5589D743A10044
     ...: 941CB215D7995921523DE21D63F7377E97E3A8AB23D79F55603CC2737D8015'}],
     ...:       dtype=object)
 

In [200]: df = pd.DataFrame(s[0], index=[0])

In [201]: df
Out[201]: 
                                                name  ttl  type  clas                                               data
0  pt.96qt6m0l6udrwon11jybxhvz0y7p1ixjisvowh52mtr...   60    10     1  E9000328A013AAC5747648480103C414DCCB01070E1105...
```